# Jquery and old IE versions

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I made my site with Jquery and now if I test it in an old IE version like 5.5 and 6 it completely is filled with errors in javascript. Is there a way of getting this problem to stop... and is that error in jquery?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: The real question is, why do you care about IE5.5 ? :)

Comment: well jquery 1.4.2 and also included the newest version...

Comment: Without looking at your code, it could simply be that you have used something that IE doesn't support, rather than jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently as others have already stated, jQuery doesn't support IE in version less than 6.

BUT, according to [this thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ie-5-5-5-compatibility#14737000000147575) back from 2006 (post by John Resig so it should be legit source), **jQuery was compatibile with IE 5.5+ in 2006**, meaning (based on [this history](http://jquery.org/history/)) that you can try to get it working on [jQuery 1.0](http://jquery.com/blog/2006/08/26/jquery-10/).

Answer (score 3):

No and Yes both!

No!, because those old browsers, are so outdated, that they do not recognize the new methods and functions.

Yes!, because JQuery is only compatible above IE 6, not IE 5.5, so most the codes may not work in IE 5.5, as it should.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery does not support IE versions below 6.0. jQuery Browser Compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to forget about IE5.5 forever. jQuery core is compatible with IE6+. See here:

> http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility

Your errors on IE6 can be produced by plugins which can be compatible only with newer browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery is only compatible with ie6+, for IE 5.5 it won't work -> [JQuery Browser Compatibility](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_compatibility)

If you really need to use IE 5.5, one option would to be to make a basic workable version of your site without any jQuery. Then add the JQuery functionality. Finally while loading, detect the browser version, if the browser is IE6+ proceed to load JQuery, if not skip it.

That way both browsers will be able to access your site, IE5.5 users will have a basic version and IE6+ a richer version.

The downside is that it is a lot of extra work.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're trying to support IE5.5 and IE6 because your client requested this. IE5.5 is over 12 years old and IE6 at least 10 years. It's simply unrealistic to try and provide the same experience for IE5.5 users as for Firefox 6, Safari and Chrome users.

Before you support an ancient browser, check the browser stats of your client's website or similar client's websites. Is it worth support IE6 if only 0.1% of the site's users actually use IE6?

Also check out this article about progressive enhancement and graceful degradation: http://www.sitepoint.com/progressive-enhancement-graceful-degradation-basics/